# adding checkbox to a combobox

Tags: php, sql, html

I want to add check boxes inside a combo box and then use the values of the checked boxes in my sql query.

Also I need to append the checked values to an array and then use the elements of that array in my sql query.
How can I proceed?

Comment: may be you want to add checkboxes to a *form*?

Comment: It's (pretty much|entirely) impossible to add check boxes to a HTML <select>. Can you give us an example (URL, image) of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with plain HTML, you will need JavaScript support.

A very, very nice and mature-looking jQuery based example is jQuery MultiSelect. [Site](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/04/jquery-multiselect) - [Demos](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/)